# Can I add pagination to individual blog posts in my twig file?

Tags: theming, paging

I have a views page which has all the blog articles, and you can click on a link to bring you to a single blog page.

On that single blog page I want to be able to add buttons for Previous and Next post. Something like

```
<a class="white-btn" href="{{ previous.href }}">Previous Article</a>
 <a class="white-btn" href="{{ next.href }}">Next Article</a>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That is the exact feature of the Book module.

[Book module overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/book/overview)

You can configure which types are allowed to be added as book pages. There is a Block you can place on Book pages to show Book navigation and Previous/Next links (it obeys the Book pages order).

---

Regular Views don't have a feature to center the Pager around a pagination placement.

A custom solution can be created to add that, but there are also modules you can check out that may help:

- [Pager](https://www.drupal.org/project/pager)
- [Pagerer](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagerer)